# Job scheduler not working in background when app is killed in android version 7,8,9,10?

Tags: android, android-service, android-9.0-pie, android-jobscheduler, android-10.0

I have used a timer to call a method at 15 minutes interval inside a job scheduler. But the job scheduler only running on the app running stage, if I kill the app the job scheduler was not worked. How to run the job scheduler to work after I killing my app?

here my code snippet

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startJob();
}

private void startJob(){
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this,
            RecallMyServicesis.class);

    JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setOverrideDeadline(15*60*1000)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .build();
    int result = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
    if(result == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS)
    {
        Log.d("MainActivity","Success");
    }else
    {
        Log.d("MainActivity","Failed");
    }
}
}
```

RecallMyServicesis.java

```
public class RecallMyServicesis extends JobService {

private static final String TAG = "RecallMyServicesis";

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    System.out.println("Job Fired");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println("Job Fired i : "+i);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Job Fired i : "+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
    }
    jobFinished(jobParameters, false );
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    return false;
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 ​<service android:name=".RecallMyServicesis"
              android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Job scheduler have limitations, you can either try WorkManager class or you can create a service.

Comment: I also created background service but these services are not working on phones like oppo, Lenovo, mi, etc. So I am trying to create a job scheduler service but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to work on JobScheduler and eventually, It is not working on Android 7.0. I have Samsung s7 device. But when I am deploying apk in Moto e4 which have android 7.1 version, the jobscheduler is working fine on background and app as well, even I kill the app, it is running.